# Setting overlay order with Holoviews + Plotly

Tags: python, plotly-python, holoviews

Is there a way to set the overlay order of Holoviews objects?

For instance, I can overlay an hv.Curve (short vertical straight line) onto a rectangle with a  solid fill color on Bokeh backend, but with the same code and a different backend (and the matching argument `fillcolor` instead of `color`), the `hv.Curve` becomes hidden behind the rectangle and invisible.

This is an overlay order issue, as confirmed by the `hv.Curve` being visible again after changing the `fillcolor` option to `None`.

Below are example code snippets to try on:

- Bokeh backend

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('bokeh')
r = hv.Rectangles((0, 2, 100, 4)).opts(height=300, width=1200, ylim=(0, 6), color='pink')
l = hv.Curve([(40,2), (40,4)]).opts(color='darkslategray')
r * l
```

- Plotly backend

```
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
hv.extension('plotly')
r = hv.Rectangles((0, 2, 100, 4)).opts(height=300, width=1200, ylim=(0, 6), fillcolor='pink')
l = hv.Curve([(40,2), (40,4)]).opts(color='darkslategray')
r * l
```

Since I am working with Dash, I prefer to use Plotly over Bokeh backend.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: This looks like a bug report for the Plotly backend of HoloViews; the overlay order is intended to work as you reported for the Bokeh backend. Can you please file that at https://github.com/holoviz/holoviews/issues?

Comment: With some time with no answer coming in, it looks like not just me missing something indeed. I will open an issue there then. Thanks James. Happy holidays

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue is likely due to a bug of the software instead of being solvable via Q&A. I am going to file a bug report to the GitHub issues. Thanks.